# My midle mouse button is broken

Tags: 3d-view, mouse

My midle mouse button is broken, is there a way to use the orbit with another button?

Comment: Use your left mouse and drag on the tri-colored X/Y/Z axis.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by myself

I went to:

Preferences>Keymap>3D View>3D View (Global)>add>"view3d.rotate"
[image: example]